# load values into a list using a loop

Tags: r

I am trying out sentiment analysis using R. My code is as below. 
I am trying to extract the positive and negative words to create word clouds. hence I am trying to get the list of positive and negative words in the input file.

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(plyr)
library(sentiment)
require(stringr)
pos.words=scan('positive-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';')
neg.words=scan('negative-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';')

data <- readLines("input.txt")

'''
clean the input

'''


# split into words. str_split is in the stringr package

word.list = str_split(cleaned, '\\s+')

# sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much

words = unlist(word.list)


# compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms

pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)

neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)

# match() returns the position of the matched term or NA

# we just want a TRUE/FALSE:

pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)

neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)
```

this is the for loop I am trying to implement to extract negative words. But I just get one word from the list.

```
for (w in neg.matches)
  if(!is.na(w))
    negit <- neg.words[w]
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: User error: You aren't doing any indexing on the LHS of the assignment. I'm not sure how this should be indexed because it is such a common error. But indexing it would probably not help because no error is thrown.

Comment: please refer to the answer below

Comment: If that was supposed to be an answer, it remains unclear what the question was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count = 0
for (w in neg.matches)
{  
  if(!is.na(w))
  {    
    count = count + 1
  }  

}  

negit = array(dim=c(count-1))
i = 0
for (w in neg.matches)
{  
  if(!is.na(w))
  {
    negit[i] <- neg.words[w]
    i = i + 1
  }  

}   

count = 0
for (w in pos.matches)
{  
  if(!is.na(w))
  {    
    count = count + 1
  }  

}  

posit = array(dim=c(count-1))
i = 0
for (w in pos.matches)
{  
  if(!is.na(w))
  {
    posit[i] <- pos.words[w]
    i = i + 1
  }  

}
```